# The name 'PromptBehavior' does not exist in the current context

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Trying to build a .NET core 1.1 console app with AAD using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (3.13.8).

I'm trying to use `AcquireTokenAsync` to auth like this

```
var authParam = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);
var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientId, new Uri("https://localhost/"), authParam);
result.Wait();
```

However I Intellisense underlines `PromptBehavior` and tells me that **The name 'PromptBehavior' does not exist in the current context**. I also cannot build due to this error.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Have you added `using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;` in the file?

Comment: Yes I was using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PromptBehavior`, and the flows which use it, are not defined for .NET Core, only for full .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/active-directory/adal/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.promptbehavior

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess my plan to build a .NET Core app with interactive user log in to AAD is malformed.

Comment: Which platform are you developing for?

Comment: Trying to do mac, Linux, and Windows.

Comment: What about 2.0 ? The NuGet package now supports .NET Standard 1.6, I sit on 2.0 and still cant see the PromptBehavior.

Comment: Same story. `PromptBehavior` is only relevant for platforms where an interactive prompt UI is displayed. This functionality is only available when targetting .NET Framework (i.e. Windows desktop), and Xamarin (i.e. iOS/Android).